# How to grab text from URL and place in JS array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I've stated previously that I am very new to JavaScript and HTML. I'm creating a small search tool and I'm very confused as to how to get text from a URL and put it in my JS array.

For example, let's say the URL is: http://www.somethingrandom.com/poop
In that URL, there's a couple of words: "something", "everything", "nothing"
Literally just that. It's in a pre tag in HTML, and that's it.

Now, my JS code, I want it to open up that URL, and take those words and place them in a string/list/array, whatever, it could be anything as long as it can happen, I can manipulate it further later.

I have this so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function getWords(){
    var url = "http://www.somethingrandom.com/poop"
    var win = window.open( url );
    window.onload = function(){
      var list = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
      var listLength = list.length;
      alert( listLength);
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="1" onClick="getWords();">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work however.. And I'm not sure why. :( Please help.

Comment: I don't see any `<pre>` tags anywhere..?

Comment: Do you really want to be opening up the url in a new window or would it be sufficient to use AJAX and make the process invisible to the use?

Comment: @RUJordan I said earlier that the URL is only a pre tag that contains a couple of words. What I wanted was the JS to open the URL and grab those words and place them in a list/array/strings.

Comment: When you use window.open it opens a new window so the other code after that doesn't get executed

Comment: @ogc-nick Honestly, that would be best, but I do not know ANY AJAX whatsoever. And would need some guiding for that.. :(

Comment: @HabenAmare Yes, I'm aware of that. I was wondering if there's a way to make that work tho.

Comment: [To learn about ajax using jquery for beginners](http://www.elated.com/articles/ajax-with-jquery-a-beginners-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX request and you will have access to the returned content.

Using jQuery:

```
  function getWords(){
    var url = "http://www.somethingrandom.com/poop"
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      var list = $('pre:eq(0)', data).html;
      var listLength = list.length;
      alert( listLength);
    }, 'html');
  }
```

Comment: So I would really have to use another language to conquer this? Because I am not familiar with AJAX or jQuery at all.

Comment: No, there is no other language. Just download jQuery from the website, add it to yoru website like any other script, and replace your function with this one. Viola! AJAX is just a fancy word for javascript making an (asynchronous) request to the server.

Comment: Hi, so I've done just that, and I did the same thing with the buttons code I posted up top, but it still doesn't work. Nothing pops up. :(